# single secure executable for tidesdk

Tags: tidesdk, tidekit

I just started looking into [TideSdk](http://www.tidesdk.org/) and noticed that when I "compile" (or package) a project (in Win-7), I get all of these dependecies which is actually the un-compiled source code for the app.

Is there any way to:

1. Have Tide SDK package a file to one executable
2. Not have the source code visible in any way, shape, or form in the final executable?

If none of those are possible, is there an alternative that can to these things?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We are working on a solution. There are a few possibilities. The only thing that is possible currently is to obfuscate your code using google closure library through a tidebuilder option.

Comment: Has there been any movement on when this will be available as part of tidesdk.. Id love to package a project as a single exe

Comment: @fairwinds Are there any updates on this answer? I would like to send my app to people who use both macs and pcs.

Comment: @MadsterMaddness Yes there is. As you may have discovered, we've been focused on the development of TideKit (http://www.tidekit.com) over the past two years. TideKit is for app development across all operating systems, screens and devices using a single code base written in JavaScript. You can develop mobile, desktop, and web apps with TideKit and you can easily migrate from TideSDK to TideKit. TideKit has this capability baked in. We are in a reservations mode for TideKit currently and it will be released incrementally. First to those with reservations.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on google when trying to do something similar.  It is annoying but seems to work.
http://coffeecone.com/post/36127491095/howto-single-exe-for-tidesdk

Answer (score 0):

I use the application virtualization app Cameyo for this purpose. http://www.cameyo.com/