# how is Wunderlist source code protected?

Tags: tidesdk, wunderlist

I am trying to build a simple app using tidesdk , but unfortunately as stated here :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14207566/1724929

that currently there is no way to protect the source code which is visible to the app users.
but after taking a look at  [wunderlist](http://www.wunderlist.com) for Windows which is built using tidesdk and .net framework , i saw that the source code is not visible also i searched if it were hidden somewhere but i found nothing , so any one have an idea how they protect the source code from being visible . is there any tool or something to achive that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latest version of Wunderlist is not built using TideSDK. They have re-implemented all different versions pure natively on each platform they are supporting.

TideSDK currently does not support Code hiding however the Developers of TideSDK are developing TideKit which is releasing soon with a new CLI, app and will provide platform builds. It will also provide Code Hiding. You can follow recent developments at http://www.tidekit.com. The video of what is coming is here: http://youtu.be/aE7gN-d0GhU. This will give you modern tools to use where the experience of creating and your projects is much better.

Comment: i read about tidekit and it seems promising , but what about its cost ? should i buy a licence to use it or it will be freely available just like tidesdk ?

Comment: TideKit would be available at affordable price for everybody. TideKit reservations will be available soon .. stay tuned and follow us on twitter @tidekit for getting latest updates about TideKit.